# tkinter textbox entry to save in .txt

Tags: python, tkinter

This is I want to do:

1. display a window with a text field and a button
2. user enters text and presses the button
3. The text is saved in .txt.

I have this mistake: `TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'`

I cant get from scrolledtext and theres only way to use entry?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

gui = Tk()

#writing to txt file.txt
def writeFile():
    file = open('save_text.txt', 'a+')
    file.write(scrtxt.get() + '\n' + '\n')
    file.close()
    scrtxt.delete(0, END)

scrtxt = ScrolledText(gui, height=5, padx = 10, pady = 10); scrtxt.grid(row=1, column=1)

#button to save text
buttonWrite = Button(gui)
buttonWrite.config(text='Save text',padx = 10, pady = 10, command = writeFile)
buttonWrite.grid(row=10, column=1)

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read up on [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: The documentation for the text widget is pretty clear that you have to pass one or two indexes to the `get` method.

Answer (score 0):

Change writeFile() to this:

```
def writeFile():
    file = open('save_text.txt', 'a+')
    file.write(scrtxt.get("1.0", END) + '\n' + '\n')
    file.close()
    scrtxt.delete("1.0", END)
```

"1.0" means line 1 and column 0 (Column starts counting from 0)

Comment: Awesome Bogdan! Thank you!